# How to select a range of elements with mouse (e.g. calendar date-range picker)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is simple I guess. I'm making a full calendar with Jquery. I want to know how can I do something like I'll show on the pictures.
User selected day 3 of month (it will appear as blue) and if he mouse hover on 8 all the numbers inside that range get a class. So.. the 4,5,6,7,8 get something. If he leaves 8 and return back 7 the 8 has no class added, should remove.

Calendar showing my idea, I did it manually:
[image: Calendar showing my idea, I did it manually]

Calendar showing that I have at this moment:
[image: Calendar showing that I have at this moment]

HTML

```
                <div class="new-calendar-inside">
                <div class="month-and-year-calendar">
                    <div class="left-arrow prev-month"></div>
                    <div class="month-year actual"></div>
                    <div class="right-arrow next-month"><i class="icon chevron right"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="calendar-days-list">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr class="days-of-the-week">
                            <th>S</th>
                            <th>T</th>
                            <th>Q</th>
                            <th>Q</th>
                            <th>S</th>
                            <th>S</th>
                            <th>D</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar-buttons">
                <button class="new-button no-border-button">Cancelar</button>
                <button id="confirm" class="new-button no-border-button">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQUERY

```
this.getCalendarTable().on("click", "td", function () {


        var row = _this.getCalendarTable().find(".selected");
        var rowOrange = _this.getCalendarTable().find(".selected-orange");
        var table = _this.getCalendarTable();


        if (_this.getContainer().find(".new-calendar.simple").hasClass("mini")) {
            if ($(this).text() != "") {
            if (_this.getContainer().find(".new-calendar.simple").hasClass("simple")) {
                // $('.new-calendar.simple').find(".border-left").removeClass("border-left");
                if ($(this).text() != "") {
                    if (row.length < 2) {

                        $(this).addClass("selected");
                        // ADICIONAR HOVER COM RATO ENQUANTO ESCOLHE ULTIMO
                        var days = $('.table td'),
                            first = days.index($('td.selected:first')),
                            last = 60;
                        var rangeDays = days.slice(first, last);

                        $(rangeDays).on("mouseover, mouseout", function () {
                            last = $(days).index($(this));
                            $(this).addClass("active");
                        });
                        _this.getContainer().find(".border-left").removeClass("border-left");
                        _this.getContainer().find(".border-right").removeClass("border-right");
                        _this.getContainer().find(".selected").eq(0).addClass("border-left");
                        _this.getContainer().find(".selected").eq(1).addClass("border-right");

                        _this.firstNumberCalendar();
                        $('td:contains(31)').addClass("border-right");
                    } else if (row.length > 1) {

                        row.removeClass("selected");
                        table.find(".active").removeClass("active");
                        $(this).addClass("selected");
                    }

                    if (row.length == 1) {
                        var last = days.index($('td.selected:last'));
                        var newSlice = days.slice(first, last);
                        newSlice.addClass("active");
                        $(rangeDays).off('mouseover');
                        $(rangeDays).off('mouseout');
                    }
                }
            }
```

Probably I need to get the last position as mouse hover but I don't know how to do it.

Regards.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle  with the code so can take look and help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use mouseover and mouseout for the exact reason you've encountered.

Instead keep track of the start and end indices during the mouse events. Then simply compare if each day is between that range.

- Make sure to take into account that `end` may be < `start` if the user selects in reverse order.
- Also make sure to consider that the mouse may be released while hovering on no particular day.

**1 click / drag**:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = i + 1;
  div.appendChild(span);
  span.addEventListener('mousedown', () => beginSelection(i));
  span.addEventListener('mousemove', () => updateSelection(i));
  span.addEventListener('mouseup', () => endSelection(i));
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => endSelection());

let selecting, start, end;

let beginSelection = i => {
  selecting = true;
  start = i;
  updateSelection(i);
};

let endSelection = (i = end) => {
  updateSelection(i);
  selecting = false;
};

let updateSelection = i => {
  if (selecting)
    end = i;
  [...document.querySelectorAll('span')].forEach((span, i) =>
    span.classList.toggle('selected', i >= start && i <= end || i >= end && i <= start));
};
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}

span.selected {
  background: #adf;
}

span:hover:not(.selected) {
  background: #cfefff;
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```

**2 clicks**:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = i + 1;
  div.appendChild(span);
  span.addEventListener('click', () => toggleSelection(i));
  span.addEventListener('mousemove', () => updateSelection(i));
}

let selecting, start, end;

let toggleSelection = i => {
  if (selecting)
    endSelection(i);
  else
    beginSelection(i);
};

let beginSelection = i => {
  selecting = true;
  start = i;
  updateSelection(i);
};

let endSelection = (i = end) => {
  updateSelection(i);
  selecting = false;
};

let updateSelection = i => {
  if (selecting)
    end = i;
  [...document.querySelectorAll('span')].forEach((span, i) =>
    span.classList.toggle('selected', i >= start && i <= end || i >= end && i <= start));
};
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}

span.selected {
  background: #adf;
}

span:hover:not(.selected) {
  background: #cfefff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
```

Comment: How can I make that but without mouse clicking? I want it with mouse hover if possible.. is that hard to do?

Comment: How would the user select 14-15 if they have to hover over 13 to get to 14? Or do you mean you want the user to click twice (14 and 15) instead of once and drag (down on 14, up on 15)?

Comment: Updated to include both approaches

Comment: EDIT: I got a bug I don't know why. When hover on the 2rd element it will hover the 4th one. Also with the lines, If I hover the 3rd line it will hover the 1st

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. You run the code snippet, hover over '2', don't click, and '4' becomes blue?

Comment: Nvm. I just deleted last comment. I did it!! Thank you

Comment: Is there anyway that I select for e.g 3 and 8 If I select 4 the 3 change to 4.. I mean, the closest one change for where user wants, is this viable or will get bugs?